# Replacing duplicates in a list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list that looks like:

```
{{-5,0,-8,-3},{0,3,-3,0},{3,-4,0,-7},{-4,-1,-7,-4},{-1,4,-4,1},{4,-3,1,-6},{-3,0,-6,-3},{0,2,-3,-1},{2,5,-1,2},{5,-2,2,-5}}
```

I want to replace duplicate values in each sublist by their value + 12:

```
{{-5,0,-8,-3},{0,3,-3,12},{3,-4,0,-7},{-4,-1,-7,8},{-1,4,-4,1},{4,-3,1,-6},{-3,0,-6,9},{0,2,-3,-1},{2,5,-1,14},{5,-2,2,-5}}
```

How can I do that?

*Duplicate values might not necessarily be at first and last position of each sublist.

Comment: Should `{-3, 0, -3, -3}` become `{-3, 0, 9, 9}` or `{-3, 0, 9, 21}`?

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {{-5,0,-8,-3}, {0,3,-3,0}, {3,-4,0,-7}, {-4,-1,-7,-4}, {-1,4,-4,1}, 
  {4,-3,1,-6}, {-3,0,-6,-3}, {0,2,-3,-1}, {2,5,-1,2}, {5,-2,2,-5}};
```

[**`Replace`**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Replace.html):

```
Replace[{a___, x_, b___, x_, c___}:> {a, x, b, x + 12, c}] /@ list
```

> {{-5, 0, -8, -3}, {0, 3, -3, 12}, {3, -4, 0, -7}, {-4, -1, -7, 
>     8}, {-1, 4, -4, 1}, {4, -3, 1, -6}, {-3, 0, -6, 9}, {0, 
>     2, -3, -1}, {2, 5, -1, 14}, {5, -2, 2, -5}}

**Memoization:** Re-define `f[x]` to become `g[x]` (`x + 12` in OP example) after first occurrence of `x`:

```
ClearAll[mapAtDuplicates]
mapAtDuplicates[g_] :=  Module[{f}, f[x_] := (f[x] = g[x]; x); f /@ #] &;

Map[mapAtDuplicates[# + 12 &]] @ list
```

> {{-5, 0, -8, -3}, {0, 3, -3, 12}, {3, -4, 0, -7}, {-4, -1, -7, 
>       8}, {-1, 4, -4, 1}, {4, -3, 1, -6}, {-3, 0, -6, 9}, {0, 
>       2, -3, -1}, {2, 5, -1, 14}, {5, -2, 2, -5}}

```
Map[mapAtDuplicates[# + z &]] @ {{1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 4, 2, 2, 2}}
```

> {{1, 1 + z, 2, 3, 2 + z, 1 + z, 2 + z},
>   {1, 2, 2 + z, 3, 2 + z, 4, 2 + z, 2 + z, 2 + z}}

Answer (score 2):

A solution using [Nearest](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nearest.html):

```
list = {{-5,0,-8,-3}, {0,3,-3,0}, {3,-4,0,-7}, {-4,-1,-7,-4}, {-1,4,-4,1}, 
  {4,-3,1,-6}, {-3,0,-6,-3}, {0,2,-3,-1}, {2,5,-1,2}, {5,-2,2,-5}};
Map[
  MapAt[
    # + 12 &,
    #, Complement[ Array[List, Length@#], Nearest[#->"Index", #, 1] ]
  ] &, list
]
```